# Which stat do the Crafting rooms use?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm confused by the Crafting rooms - I vaguely remember seeing that the Weapon Workshop uses Agility at one point, but then it changed to Strength? I may just be insane however and imagining things.

So what stats do the Weapon Workshop and the Outfit Workshop use?

**EDIT:** After looking at the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_workshop), the crafting time suggests a possible maximum SPECIAL attribute being over 10, but this is not clarified as to *which* SPECIAL, or SPECIAL(s) - though I would believe this is likely contributed by gear:

> Total SPECIAL = Crafting Time 
>   102 = *(x)* mins 
>   102/6 dwellers = 17 per dweller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that these rooms are dependant on the item being crafted. By dragging another dweller over a Crafting room that was currently active (i.e. the room was in the process of crafting a weapon/outfit) the contribution of that Dweller's relevant stat is identified.

[image: Dragging a Dweller over the Weapon Workshop]

[image: Dragging another Dweller over the Weapon Workshop]

This can also be identified when choosing an item to craft:

[image: Relevant SPECIAL stat required to craft the item]

So for example, pistols require Agility, rifles require Perception, shotguns require Endurance, and most other weapons require Strength.

There is a specific group of weapons called "Institute" weapons, that require Intelligence to build.

This is the same for the Outfit Workshop.