# How are weapons affected by SPECIAL?

Tags: fallout-shelter

After having a look at the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_workshop) for crafting, each weapon had an Ability listed next to it, possibly suggesting that each weapon is affected by a dweller's SPECIAL.

Is this the case?

To clarify - I'm asking how a weapon is affected by a dweller's SPECIAL stats. For example, we can see here:

[image: Weapons and Abilites]

Each weapon has an "Ability" listed.

- The 10mm pistol has an "A" (Agility)
- The BB gun has a "P" (Perception)

This suggests that each weapon is affected by their corresponding Ability. So for example, would a Dweller weilding a 10mm pistol with 10 Agility do more damage than a Dweller with 5 Agility?

Comment: @Timelord64 I don't see anything about weapons in that question. I'm talking about a specific weapon in some way being affected by a specific stat. That question/answer just covers what the SPECIAL affects in/out of the Vault. I'll edit the question to specify.

Comment: @Timelord64 edited. I can see there is a bit of a clear difference between the first half and the second - there does appear to be two questions here. If you feel the same I'll remove the first half

Comment: I understand the relation between the ability listed and the weapon in those three circumstances, but there are weapons that also have Intelligence listed. If the ability does nothing, (if only to specify perhaps some kind of "weapon/skill class"), why is the ability listed at all?

Comment: And just to confirm, this is definetly not the ability trait required to make the gun faster, as mentioned directly above the table? I also notice that intelligence guns are all institute-based, while strength guns are all the big weapons, such as flamers and RPGS

Comment: Actually you might be onto something there... 2 seconds...

Comment: I'm off, anyway. I trust you'll sort it out either way. Hope I've helped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which stat does the Crafting rooms use?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267476/which-stat-does-the-crafting-rooms-use)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mentioned stat for each weapon is the stat that is used for building the weapon. **It affects the time to construct the weapon in a workshop.**

The workshop initially has no main stat (as a power plant has S, labs have I, etc), but when you allocate dwellers here and select some weapon to build, it will get the stat associated with the weapon as its primary stat. The specific stat can be different, depending on which weapon you chose.

So say you want to build a weapon with S - then, if you assign dwellers with high S, it will go faster. Also, you can equip outfits on them, so the best stat value for a dweller can be 10 + 7, which can make crafting even legendaries really fast if you have all the dwellers properly equipped. You can go down to something like 2m30s for rare weapons, and like 10-12 hours (if I remember correctly) for some legendaries.

Those stats have **no use other than computing the crafting time**.

Crafting outfits works the same.

Answer (score 5):

As I've discovered, this has nothing to do with a weapon's, or Dweller's attributes. What this is referring to is the stat required to *make* the weapon.

Eg., Pistols generally require Agility, Rifles generally require Perception, there are a few weapons listed as "Institute" weapons that are the only ones that require intellingence to build, and the rest require Strength **to build**.

This has nothing to do with the weapon's performance.

Answer (score -2):

not so sure about the stat not affecting weapons - my dwellers with high perception seem to attack more often when using the guass rifle - both with max agility - during quests in the wasteland anyway

Comment: This seems like it should've been a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Stats affect damage and speed - the weapon itself has no correlation with the stats. A dweller with high perception will *always* attack faster than a dweller with low perception, regardless of the weapon they are using.

Comment: General consensus seems to be that it's agility, not perception, which controls attack rate.  If you've got a video of two dwellers with identical weapons and agility, with differing perception, attacking at different rates (taking into account the observation that walking around seems to delay the next attack), that would be very interesting to see.